# I tried to record video capture using Xcode Simulator, but the sound does not recorded

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, video-capture, audio, screen-capture

I tried to use iShowU HD to make a video capture from Xcode simulator for my app, but the sound did not recorded.  The sound recorded from other applications, like youtube from browser, etc.  But not from the xcode simulator?

Anyone has some suggestions how to fix the problem?

Thanks

Comment: so is this a problem with "iShowU HD" or is there no sound coming out of your simulator at all?

Comment: iShowU HD can record the sound from other applications like youtube from browser.  but the sound from simulator is not recored. So the problem is with xcode simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this tutorial](http://support.shinywhitebox.com/hc/en-us/articles/200173170-I-can-t-record-audio-), you need to have the correct input device selected in the Macintosh's Sound Preference Pane for iShowU to be able to pick up audio.

Sounds like you should have "Soundflower (2ch)" (2 channel) selected as your input source.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Let me try to restart simulator after I start iShowU HD.

Comment: Thank you so much.  It works now!!  I restarted the simulator after I started iShowU.